# Is it possible to globally precache an image by creating an image element and waiting for it to load?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a code which spawns text blocks with images one by one and I need to wait until all the images are fully loaded and occupy their actual width and height in the viewport.
Every image element has a quite a few attributes, so if I implement a separate function which takes an image URL as an input and spits an image element - I would have to not only assign all the needed attributes to it, but also manually append that element into the HTML of the text block.

My question is: If I wait for the image to load inside a separate function which doesn't return the resulting image element and immediately create another image element with the same URL - would this procedure have the same effect as creating an image element, waiting for it to load and appending that very element ?

Comment: Why don't you wait for the ones' inside your "text block"? Is something like https://jsfiddle.net/1yat39v7/ what you're after?

Comment: @Kaiido Thank you very much for a beautiful example. I will consider doing what you suggested